# Wrong proportion when Unwrapping

Tags: uv

After some research, I know this question has been asked before.
But first of all, I specify that yes, I applied the scale with Ctrl+A and "All transform" or "Scale"...

Let me explain, I have a texture with grass on it, and I try to create planes of the same size as the grass, to then do my unwrap on my texture.

The problem is that after having unwrapped, even with "Project from view", the proportions of my plane is not respected in the UV Editor...
[image: my screenshot]

As you can see on the image, in UV Editor, the rectangle does not have the same ratio of my rectangle on the right in my edit view...
The scale of my object is 1,1,1.
In addition to that I modified the proportions of my object in Edit mode , and not in object mode, that was already in 1,1,1...

If anyone has a solution I would really appreciate it!
I'm completely lost ..

Maybe i'm doing this to the wrong way ?..

Have a nice day!

Answer (score 4):

If there is no *Image Texture* in the object's material, the UV is projected with the correct aspect ratio in relation to a square space. A UV map is always normalized from bottom left at (0, 0) to top right at (1, 1).

If you now add an *Image Texture* node in a material on the object which has a different aspect than a 1:1 square, the UV map still goes from (0, 0) to (1, 1), only that the aspect ratio now fits the one of the image which means the UVs get stretched on X or Y depending on the image.

If you want the faces to have the correct aspect ratio on the non-square image, you have to either repeat the unwrapping with the image texture selected (which would be the simplest solution) or - if you already arranged the UVs in some way which you don't want to have to recreate - scale the UVs on Y by the factor X/Y of the image ratio or scale on X by the factor Y/X.

When unwrapping the UVs again after selecting the image texture with *Project from View* it could be that the aspect ratio does not change correctly, in this case it is best to first choose <kbd>U</kbd> > *UV Mapping* > *Reset* and then try again.

Note: As mentioned above, the aspect ratio of a selected image texture will be used as reference. So if your material has multiple image textures, the UVs will be fit to the one selected - no matter which image might be visible in the *UV Editor* background.